# Reading pixels from UIImage results in BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I wrote this code that is supposed to NSLog all non-white pixels as a test before going further.

This is my code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
if(!pixelData) {
    return;
}

const UInt8 *buffer = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
CFRelease(pixelData);

for(int y = 0; y < image.size.height; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < image.size.width; x++) {
        int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width  * y) + x) * 4;

        UInt8 red = buffer[pixelInfo];
        UInt8 green = buffer[(pixelInfo + 1)];
        UInt8 blue = buffer[pixelInfo + 2];
        UInt8 alpha = buffer[pixelInfo + 3];

        if(red != 0xff && green != 0xff && blue != 0xff){
            NSLog(@"R: %hhu, G: %hhu, B: %hhu, A: %hhu", red, green, blue, alpha);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I build an app, it iterates for a moment and then throws `BAD_ACCESS` error on line:
`UInt8 red = buffer[pixelInfo];`. What could be the issue?

Is this the fastest method to iterate through pixels?

Comment: I ran the above snippet and it didn't give me any error using a 75 × 35 pixels  image. I added the code in View did load.

Comment: My image is much bigger, but that shouldn't be an issue:(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a buffer size error.
*buffer* has the size of width x height, and *pixelInfo* has a 4 multiplier.
I think you need to create an array 4 times bigger and save each pixel color of buffer in this new array. But you have to be careful not to read more of the size of the buffer.

Comment: Buffer has the size taken from CFDataGetBytePtr which is correct amount of bytes.